# Pointwise bound of the gradient of solutions of heat equations in the half-space.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, heat-equation, upper-lower-bounds, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I want to investigate the decay of $L(x)$:

$$L(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^3_+} \nabla_x \Phi(x-y,1/2)(\eta(y)g(y))dy,$$

where $g:\mathbb{R}^3_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is infinitely smooth away from the origin with $|g(y)|\leq\frac{1}{|y|}$ for all $y$. Here $\eta(y) \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a cut-off function such that  $\eta(y)=1$ for $|y|<1$.

Now, the fundamental solution $\Phi$ of the heat equations is as usual,
$$ \Phi(x,t)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}$$
for any $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \times (0,\infty)$.

Claim: $L(x)$ is bounded roughly by $C(1+|x|)^{-2},$ or probably by $C e^{-x^2/4}$ for some constant $C$ not depending on $|x|$. Here $x\in\mathbb{R}^3_+$.

What I have done is the following:

One can divide the half-space into two components $|x-y|\geq |x|/2$ and $|x-y|<|x|/2$, say $L = L_1 + L_2$. Then, concerned with $L_1$,
$$ L_1 \lesssim e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4}} \int_{M} \frac{|y-x|}{|y|} dy \lesssim (1+|x|)e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4}},$$
where $M$ is the compact support of $\eta$. My problem is that the decay may not be optimal!

Geometrically, the other case implies $|y|>|x|/2$, so $$ L_2 \lesssim |x|(1/|x|)\int_M e^{-|x-y|^2/2}dy \lesssim  \int_M e^{-|x|^2/4}dy \lesssim e^{-|x|^2/4},$$
which seem to be optimal.

Let me know how to obtain the faster decay when $|x-y|>|x|/2$ or suggest a theme that I can work on!

Comment: So is your $k=1$?

Comment: Yes, $k=1$! Sorry for the misleading, it came from the similar estimates for other $k$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Observe if $|x|\gg |y|$ then we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{B_1(0)} \frac{\nabla_x e^{-|x-y|^2}}{|y|}\ dy\right| \sim& \left|\int_{B_1(0)} \frac{e^{-|x-y|^2}}{|y|}(x-y)\ dy\right| \geq \int_{B_1(0)}\frac{e^{-|x-y|^2}}{|y|}(|x|-|y|)\ dy\\
 \geq&\ \frac{|x|}{2}\int_{B_1(0)}\frac{e^{-|x-y|^2}}{|y|}\ dy \sim |x| e^{-|x|^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Would you explain how this is related to my problem? I cannot grasp that this lower bound matters. My target is exponential decay(or upper bound) without polynomial term!